# iPhone SDK: How to add a compiled static library to my project?(AQGridView)

Tags: iphone, ios

I plan to use AQGridView which I found on github, it says:

***"This project compiles to a static library which you can include, or you can just reference the source files directly. Note that there are some resources to copy into your project for the tableview-style selection backgrounds."***

But I have no idea what does this means, can anyone one tell me clearly the steps how can I add this to my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. After compiling the project, you'll get a `dylib`-file (you may already have it?).
2. Now, drag the `dylib`-file to your app-Xcode-project.
3. Go to your target settings and add the `includes`-folder to your `Header Search Paths` so that you can use it's public classes.
4. Now make sure it's in your target's 'Link with library'-list.
5. Compile!

Comment: I opened the project with xcode, and built it where do I suppose to find the dylib file?

Comment: ah ok I was expecting something with dylib extension..it has .a

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to say that ... At Mac OS X they have a `dylib`-extension, but for iPhone-libs that don't (I don't exactly know why).

Comment: also what is includes folder?

Comment: Probably the folder all `.h`-files are in.

Comment: @TimvanElsloo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2372/discussion-between-xdeveloper-and-tim-van-elsloo)

Comment: I couldnt find what is includes folder and how to add it